# custom pagination in jquery datatable using angularJS not working in second page onwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable, pagination

I have removed the pagination feature from datatable by setting pagination as false. I am fetching 10 rows per call from my DB, now I have set custom buttons for next and previous which makes DB calls to fetch the data. It is working fine. Now my problem is that on first call, the Datatable appears properly, but on clicking next or previous button, the data shows in the table but datatable breaks up. By breaking up, I mean that the headers and styling is not visible. Any pointers on how can I reset the datatable on call of the next or previous button? Thanks.

```
plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/sc39Vl4IGb6owQtLAHnS?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

I visited your  plunker there after two times i clicked on "Next" button it goes  to  file for json request at  data3.txt  and there 404 error shown in browser console (firebug) if anyhow you need disable button once it reached to last page using

```
$scope.nextDisabled = "true";
```

Comment: i have fixed that in my code, that is not the issue, that is just for showing the problem, which is, in the 2nd page, the Datatable is not working

Comment: delete this answer please @khajaamin, as it is not the answer and users dont check if it answered